# Is there a way to intuitively think about AUC associated with an ROC plot in the case where our predictions are binary?

Tags: prediction, binary-data, roc

Suppose we have a true set of labels, which are either $0,1$, and we have a set of predicted labels that are also either $0,1$. In this case, a possible ROC plot has one point connecting the line, with the cutoffs being taken at infinity, 1, and 0.

In this case, is there a nice way to think about the AUC in terms of the ROC plot? Or is such a geometric interpretation not possible? Usually if the predictions were taken on a continuous scale, each point on the ROC curve is the tradeoffs between the true positives and false positives at that point cutoff. Does such an interpretation generalize? Thanks.

Comment: Binary classification models almost always have somewhat continuous representations internally. It's only at the very end they are turned into binary labels. Just  get your model's predictions before that last step.